# How to add suffix to URL link (/?currency=usd)

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8

When switching currency between CAD and USD dollars. The product url does not change. It stay the same
www.example.com/sport-equipment/soccer-ball/

I need to add the suffix to produt url such as **?currency=usd** or **?currency=cad**

When switching the currency to CAD (Canadian dollar) the url link should look like this: 
www.example.com/sport-equipment/soccer-ball/**?currency=cad**

When switching the currency to USD (US dollar) the url link should look like this: 
www.example.com/sport-equipment/soccer-ball/**?currency=usd**

Please help out, I've been trying for the past week, and cannot find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you trying to do this? Magento reads the current currency from a cookie which is set when you use the currency switcher input at the top of the page. Look at the option value for each currency:

```
http://example.com/directory/currency/switch/currency/CAD/uenc/some_form_key/
```

See: https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/5345da52778cc6f5f31938ffd21fccfdd353435c/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Store.php#L851

---

Seeing your comment, I think there could be a number of approaches here. Ultimately, you will need to call:

```
Mage::app()->getStore()->setCurrentCurrencyCode($code)
```

How you go about doing this is up to you. The problem I'm sure you're running into is that changing the visitor's currency requires a page reload to alter the cookie and those feed service crawlers I'm guessing just ignore the redirect.

You may need to create your own controller that will listen for a `currency` parameter, set the store's currency, and then load/render the layout making it effectively look like your normal product page. You should also be able to refine the request flow based on the feed service crawler's user agent (which I'm guessing would be unique to that service). That way when someone visits your custom controller, you can just redirect them to the default product page.

Alternatively, you could rewrite the product controller to handle this as well, which might be a little cleaner in this case but you may wish to keep this stuff separate from your normal product controller.

Comment: The reason why I am doing is: I would like to send products feeds but the TheFeed.com and Google Shopping website accepts USD currency. My website base currency is CAD (cad dollar). When I switch to USD currency, it does not reflect in the link URL that the prices are in USD. If I send these urls to thefeed.com the website will upload default prices which are in CAD rather than USD. So I want to send links with suffixes www.example.com/sport-equipment/soccer-ball/?currency=usd. This way it will for sure upload US prices to the feeds.

Comment: Could you please help me out, which line to edit so all product links will have suffix "?currency=usd" at the end when I switch to US prices.

Comment: Well if your base currency is CAD with single store, technically the result is correct. You should create a separate website with website pricing for USD and use that as the basis of the feeds.

Comment: Do you think its possible to edit the code, so the Url links have this code "?currency=usd" when switched USD  ? Instead of creating a separate website ?

To make it simple, all i need is some kind of ending at the end of the url when I switch to USD currency. This way I know for sure the page will show US prices.

Comment: Setting a different website would probably be the smartest way to go.

Comment: Maybe  its possible to do so by adding another store-view ?

Comment: Here's some info on different configs for multi-store type setups: http://www.crucialwebhost.com/kb/how-to-setup-multiple-magento-stores/  -- Depending on your requirements, you could set up either a separate domain/sub-domain, for example. There should be plenty of info available online on setting this up.

Comment: You are fiddling with the internals of Magento, it is not designed to work the way you are expecting. Plus when people come to your site via USD they will checkout in CAD, it does not build trust. You need to do it properly, website pricing and two separate websites each with a store view so USD visitors can checkout in USD. Technically you can pretty much do anything given the time and resources, but that does not mean it is smart.

Comment: Actually there is a module if you choose USD currency you will actually checkout in USD currency. If you choose CAD currency, you will checkout in CAD.

Comment: Yes we know of it, but it only solves ~20% of the problem for local currency checkout, fx conversions, margins, ddp prices - and people have been having some serious reindexing issues with it installed as it seems to touches the core pricing process - any little disturbance from extensions to an upgrade and the house of cards falls down. We use something else but it is enterprise grade to fix 100% of the problem without the stability issues - so the advice still stands - use Magento core.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem and I've solved it like this:

The `controller_action_layout_load_before` event, which is fired on every page load is observed. The observer method checks if the `currency` parameter is present in the current URL.

If it is, it first checks if the currency code from the URL parameter is  an allowed currency with the `Mage_Core_Model_Store::getAvailableCurrencyCodes` method. If the currency is allowed,  it switches the current currency for the store by calling the `Mage_Core_Model_Store::setCurrentCurrencyCode` method.

I've packed it up into an extension on Github: https://github.com/mobweb/MobWeb_SwitchCurrencyByURL.

Comment: You're welcome. :) Feel free to "Accept" my answer if you feel that it solved your problem.